# SSMS Version for - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssms

I have Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2014.

[image]

What version of SQL Server Management Studio must be installed for the proper functioning of the data and configuration of the remote connection?

Is that you can give a link to the download.

Thank you

----------------Edited -----------------

After instal SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU , i have the following error

[image]

So I want to install Visual Studio 2010 ???

Comment: Use the version that came packaged with SQL Server. I.e. 2014.

Comment: can you  give a link for download please :) , this SQL SERVER is installed with Visual Studio 2013

Comment: To elaborate on @Chris Pickford answer: to get full functionality you need to use the same or later version of SSMS as the SQL Server. Having said that you can use an earlier version but it will only support features that are present in the equivalent version of SQL Server..

Comment: Sure, download here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/

Comment: In Sql Server section, I  choose what item ?? is this : SQL Server 2014 Management Studio (x64) ???

Comment: Yes, the file name something similar to, SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU

Comment: From the error message title, it looks like you're install the 2012 version - was that intended? Apart from that, please consider asking a new question, also consider translating that error message into English (might get a broader "audience" that way).

Comment: ah ok , but how I'll find a good version of SMS 2014 without asking for subscription as in this link ( msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads  )

Comment: You can use express edition of Sql Server 2014. https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest version of SSMS at the below location,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: installation failed  : in the log, i have -> MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed, Apply complete, result: 0x800b0100, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Comment: Hi ALFA, would you mind sending your log file to ssmsfeedback at microsoft dot com. I work on the SQL Server Tools team and would like to help resolve your error.